# DISTINCT query and ORDER BY throws mySQL error

Tags: mysql, distinct

I am trying to do a DISTICNT query on one column and sort by another column that is not in the SELECT statement. I get this error:

> Query failed SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: 3065 Expression #1 of
> ORDER BY clause is not in SELECT list, references column
> 'midnites_midNite.product_in_category.sortOrder' which is not in
> SELECT list; this is incompatible with DISTINCT

I have a products_in_category sample table that has four columns, ID, cat_ID, product_ID and sortOrder. I've been trying to do a DISTICNT query on product_ID WHERE cat_ID = 9 and sort by the query values associated in the sortOrder column.

```
     ID      cat_ID  product_ID  sortOrder
+----------+--------+-----------+--------+
|    1     |    9   |     5     |    3   |
+----------+--------+-----------+--------+
|    2     |    9   |     26    |    1   |
+----------+--------+-----------+--------+
|    3     |    9   |     5     |    2   |
+----------+--------+-----------+--------+
|    4     |    9   |     7     |    4   |
+----------+--------+-----------+--------+
|    5     |    9   |     5     |    5   |
+----------+--------+-----------+--------+
|    6     |   22   |     4     |    6   |
+----------+--------+-----------+--------+

SELECT DISTINCT product_ID 
FROM product_in_category 
WHERE cat_ID = 9
```

This query returns 3 values 5, 26, 7 which is correct but I need to sort by their associated sortOrder values as well. If I use this query below it returns 5 values which is incorrect because all the values in the sortOrder column are unique.

```
SELECT DISTINCT product_ID, 
                sortOrder 
FROM product_in_category 
WHERE cat_ID = 9 
ORDER BY sortOrder
```

If I use the the query below mySQL throws this error and I understand why, sortOrder wasn't included in the SELECT statement. I am not sure how to do a DISTICNT query on the product_ID column and sort by the return value's associated sortOrder values.

> Query failed SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: 3065 Expression #1 of
> ORDER BY clause is not in SELECT list, references column
> 'midnites_midNite.product_in_category.sortOrder' which is not in
> SELECT list; this is incompatible with DISTINCT

```
SELECT DISTINCT product_ID 
FROM product_in_category 
WHERE cat_ID = 9
ORDER BY sortOrder
```

I've tried various union, join and select statements in various ways. I hope this is understand able and appreciate any help you can provide!!!

Comment: Please clarify *need to sort by their associated sortOrder* , product_ID   5 has 3 associated sortOrder which one do you want and why ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT product_ID, MIN(sortOrder) AS minSortOrder
    FROM product_in_category
    WHERE cat_ID = 9
    GROUP BY product_ID;
```

Comment: Need to add "ORDER BY minSortOrder"

Comment: @manassehkatz-Moving2Codidact It depends. I think the OP's use of ORDER BY was a failed attempt to find the MIN value.

Comment: That worked I just needed to add the ORDER BY, THANK YOU!!! With that said I am a little confused though, can you tell me why the MIN() function was able to do what it does? I know it returns the minimum value in a set of values but I am drawing a blank why it works.

Comment: @RWRuth MIN is an aggregate function that works across a set of rows. The GROUP BY tells the query that you want the MIN value of sortOrder for each set of rows with the same (distinct) product_ID value.